# .hover function transition and then a .click function that transitions to a cross which has to be clicked to transition back (custom hamburger menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

wanting to create a hover function transition and then a click function that transitions to a cross which has to be clicked to transition back (custom hamburger menu)... If you can help at all thank you!

---

```js
 $("#wrapper").hover(function() {
    $(".menu").toggleClass("transition");
  });

$("#wrapper").click(function() {
  $(".transition").toggleClass("close");
});
```

```css
.main-item {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.28, 1.54) 0.32s;
  background: black;
}

.line01 {
  top: 33.3%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.line02 {
  top: 66.6%;
  width: 65%;
  right: 0;
}

.menu.transition .line01 {
  width: 65%;
}

.menu.transition .line02 {
  width: 100%;
  top: 66%;
}

.transition.close .line01 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 49%;
  width: 100%;
}

.transition.close .line02 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 49%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="main-item menu">
    <span class="line line01"></span>
    <span class="line line02"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use bold font for your entire question.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Sorry... first time using Stackoverflow.